# I got an error while trying to push my file from git to github and this error occurs

Tags: git, github

I see:

```
git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to zeraMe1ster/Video-Sharing-Platform-Proposal.git denied to codingTrainSauhard.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/zeraMe1ster/Video-Sharing-Platform-Proposal.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Any idea what should I do ?

I have checked my config file and user name as well as email is associated with `zeraMe1ster` and not with `codingTrainSauhard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your config file is only for commit authoring, *not* for GitHub authentication.

You need to check if you have a credential helper currently caching the wrong credentials for GitHub:

```
git config credential.helper
```

If you see `manager`, then open the Windows Credential Manager to [check the `github.com` entry](https://superuser.com/a/1309197/141).

For OSX Keychain, follow "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)"

Make sure the remote origin is your repo:

```
git remote -v
# if incorrect:
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<yourAccount>/<yourRepoOrFork>
```

Comment: While i was trying to search some answer i tried to follow up this
git remote add origin https://github.com/zeraMe1ster/Video-Sharing-Platform-Proposal.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

so now i am struck for a while.

Comment: @SauhardiamSau I have edited the answer to address OSX Keychain, and the remote.

Comment: origin https://github.com/zeraMe1ster/Video-Sharing-Platform-Proposal.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/zeraMe1ster/Video-Sharing-Platform-Proposal.git (push)

i check both true as well . they are set to correct url.

Comment: @SauhardiamSau Then you don't need to update the origin URL, you only need to check your cached credentials, following https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain

Comment: git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https

tried that and still the error remains. 

I will try to re setup git from the start again and will let you know if error still exist. Thanks a lot for suggesting @VonC

Comment: @SauhardiamSau OK. Make sure `zeraMe1ster` is your GitHub account: you will need its password to properly authenticate to GitHub with it.

Comment: wait a sec i have never done that i think thats the thing can you please tell me how can i authenticate my github account with validating my password through terminal cmd? that could solve this..

Comment: @SauhardiamSau Once your credential helper is in place (and it is), the next push will trigger a popup asking for your username/password: enter `zeraMe1ster` and its password.

Comment: Aye aye captain ! @VonC